# How to sort bibliography entries according to an option in \printbibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I am trying to write a document in which bibliographies are sorted in descending order according to year. This is achieved using the option `ydnt`, but I want to provide this option as an argument to `\printbibliography` or at least as an option after loading `biblatex`. Is this possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-alphabetic, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document} 
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, sorting=ydnt]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a use case for not specifying `sorting=ydnt` as an option to be set when the `biblatex` package is loaded.

Comment: I need it because I use a template to create multiple documents using the same `.tex` file loading packages and defining settings. The default should be `sorting=none`, but for some documents, I need the option `sorting=ydnt`

Answer (score 1):

The `sorting` option was removed from `\printbibliography` a while ago and will no longer work as expected.

You can use `refcontext`s a la

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-alphabetic, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

At least in the example the output is the same if you just say `sorting=nydnt,` at loading time and use no special `refcontext` at all.